# PowerShell Remove all users from a specific group

Tags: powershell, command-line, active-directory

I'm trying to clean all users from Local Group test_group by executing the following command below on Windows 2008 R2 Standard, PowerShell 2.0.

```
Get-ADGroupMember "test_group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "test_group" $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

It throws the following error, most probably because I'm using v2.0?:

> The term 'Get-ADGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che ck the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:18 + Get-ADGroupMember <<<<
>   "test_group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "test_group" $_
>   -Confirm:$false} + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ADGroupMember:String) [], CommandNotFoundException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I tried many ideas from this article and its comments, and I couldn't get any to work but I'm not a sysadmin and I'm not sure if I'm not missing something?: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/07/28/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-remove-all-group-members-in-active-directory.aspx

Please help, I have around 300 groups to clean on Monday and I don't want to do it manually...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

not sure if you if this is a typo or this was how you were running the command but it should be get-adgroupmember

```
Get-ADGroupMember "test_group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "test_group" $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

That worked for me had to refresh the ADUC ou to see the change though

**EDIT**

import the ActiveDirectory module first then try and run the command.

```
import-module activedirectory
Get-ADGroupMember "test_group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "test_group" $_ -Confirm:$false}
```

Comment: Right, now it throws the following error: The term 'Get-ADGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Che
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ Get-ADGroupMember <<<<  "test_group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember "test_group" $_ -Confirm:$false}
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ADGroupMember:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: I think it's because I'm using PowerShell 2.0 but I cannot upgrade. Is there a workaround?

Comment: did you load the active directory module? import-module activedirectory? im pretty sure it is in powershell 2 but I dont have it to test.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you explain the steps if possible? Thanks for the patience!

Comment: see my edit above.  import the module then run the command as long as you have the AD tools installed it should load the module.

Comment: Thanks Dane, it seems to work better, but the goal is not reached:
`Remove-ADGroupMember : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation
At line:1 char:70
+ Get-ADGroupMember "test_group" | ForEach-Object {Remove-ADGroupMember <<<<  "test_group" $_ -Confirm:$false
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (test_group:ADGroup) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Insufficient access rights to perform the operation,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.M
   .Commands.RemoveADGroupMember`

Comment: It's strange, I'm admin of the server, and I can easily go to the Server Manager --> Local Users/Groups --> test_group and remove all members with a delete. On the other hand, Windows User Account Control forces me to put my credentials each time I click on the Server Manager, so it may be the reason.

Comment: You can use `Get-LocalGroupMember` and `Remove-LocalGroupMember` if working locally.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative way:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember "test_group" -Members (Get-ADGroupMember "test_group") -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: -Identity is missing after Get-ADGroupMember

Comment: This will give an error if there are no members to remove

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Zhenia Shapiro's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7994153/zhenia-shapiro) answer:

```
Get-ADGroup "test_group" | Set-ADGroup -Clear member
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set-adgroup -clear
```

the tricky part for me was to remember use ldap attr. name, "member" and not "members" that intuitively f(ol)lows from get-adgroup -prop members

To modify an object property, you must use the **LDAP** display name:
[Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617199.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not very helpful. When I type you command line I got an error "missing argument". Please discribe how your solution solves the problem.